# How to get the sum of a column value as a new column in the SQL result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table known as payment plans, I need to get the result set as in the below table.

```
CREATE TABLE PaymentPlans
(
PaymentPlanID           int, 
EmployeeID              int,        
PaidToDate              money
)

INSERT INTO PaymentPlans VALUES (1,1,100)
INSERT INTO PaymentPlans VALUES (2,1,200)
INSERT INTO PaymentPlans VALUES (3,1,150)
```

In my select query, i need an extra column which provides me the sum of 'PaidToDate'. I'm trying with the below query, where i'm getting the result set for 'Total amount paid', same as 'Paid to date'.

```
SELECT PaymentPlanID, EmployeeID, PaidToDate, SUM(PaidToDate) AS 'TOTAL AMOUNT PAID' FROM PaymentPlans group by PaymentPlanID, EmployeeID, PaidToDate

SELECT a.PaymentPlanID, a.EmployeeID, a.PaidToDate, SUM(a.PaidToDate) AS 
'TOTAL AMOUNT PAID' FROM (
SELECT PaymentPlanID, EmployeeID, PaidToDate FROM PaymentPlans
)a
GROUP BY a.PaymentPlanID, a.EmployeeID, a.PaidToDate
```

On both these scenarios, I'm getting the result as below,

```
PaymentPlanID   EmployeeID  PaidToDate  TotalAmountPaid
1               1           100.00      100.00
2               1           200.00      200.00
3               1           150.00      150.00
```

Where as i need result as below,

```
PaymentPlanID EmployeeID    PaidToDate    TotalAmountPaid
1             1             100.00        450.00
2             1             200.00        450.00
3             1             150.00        450.00
```

Please let me know what am i missing in my query.

Comment: Add another EmployeeID to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: Add another EmployeeID to the sample data !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OVER` clause. You might need to include the `PARTITION BY` clause, depending on your requirement.

```
SELECT PaymentPlanID,
       EmployeeID,
       PaidToDate,
       SUM(PaidToDate) OVER () AS TotalAmountPaid
FROM dbo.PaymentPlans;
```

Comment: hum, i think he want partition by EmployeeID

Comment: @Esperento57 quite possibly, however, we only have one employee in the sample and expected results. Hence why I mentioned `PARTITION BY` in the answer. They don't mention it in their question, so it would be total guesswork.

Comment: Yes i know but he can think it's ok but it's ok only if he have only one user into the table :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try below way

```
select *,(select sum(PaidToDate) from  PaymentPlans) as total from PaymentPlans 

PaymentPlanID   EmployeeID  PaidToDate  total
1                  1         100.00    450.00
2                  1         200.00    450.00
3                  1        150.00     450.00
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case where you have multiple customer ids and you want each row to have that customer's total amount paid you would need to join to a sub query as follows

```
SELECT 
   a.PaymentPlanID, 
   a.EmployeeID, 
   a.PaidToDate, 
   b.TotalPaidToDate AS 'TOTAL AMOUNT PAID' 
FROM PaymentPlans a
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT 
       EmployeeID, 
       SUM(PaidToDate) AS TotalPaidToDate 
    FROM PaymentPlans 
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
) b
ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Over` clause that might be executed fast if the underlying records are more.

```
SELECT 
      PaymentPlanID,EmployeeID,
      PaidToDate,SUM(PaidToDate) OVER () as total
FROM PaymentPlans
```

Answer (score 1):

For complete the discution with Larnu,

method 1:

```
SELECT PaymentPlanID,
       EmployeeID,
       PaidToDate,
       SUM(PaidToDate) OVER (partition by EmployeeID order by PaymentPlanID) AS TotalAmountPaidByEmployeeID,
       SUM(PaidToDate) OVER () AS TotalAmountPaid
FROM dbo.PaymentPlans;
```

Method 2:

```
with Total as 
(
select EmployeeID, sum(PaidToDate) TotalAmountPaidByEmployeeID
from dbo.PaymentPlans
group by EmployeeID
)
SELECT f1.*, f2.TotalAmountPaidByEmployeeID
FROM dbo.PaymentPlans f1 inner join Total f2 on f1.EmployeeID=f2.EmployeeID;
```

Method 3

```
SELECT f1.*, f3.TotalAmountPaidByEmployeeID
FROM dbo.PaymentPlans f1
cross apply
(
  select sum(PaidToDate) TotalAmountPaidByEmployeeID from dbo.PaymentPlans f2
  where f1.EmployeeID=f2.EmployeeID
) f3
```